# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor is slower than for list comprehension

Tags: python, concurrency

I'm testing a trivial function using list comprehension vs concurrent.futures:

```
class Test:

    @staticmethod
    def something(times = 1):
        return sum([1 for i in range(times)])

    @staticmethod
    def simulate1(function, N):
        l = []

        for i in range(N):
            outcome = function()
            l.append(outcome)

        return sum(l) / N

    @staticmethod
    def simulate2(function, N):
        import concurrent.futures

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            l = [outcome for outcome in executor.map(lambda x: function(), range(N))]

        return sum(l) / N

    @staticmethod
    def simulate3(function, N):
        import concurrent.futures

        l = 0

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(function) for i in range(N)]
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                l += future.result()

        return l / N

def simulation():
    simulationRate = 100000

    import datetime

    s = datetime.datetime.now()
    o = Test.simulate1(lambda : Test.something(10), simulationRate)
    print((datetime.datetime.now() - s))

    s = datetime.datetime.now()
    o = Test.simulate2(lambda : Test.something(10), simulationRate)
    print((datetime.datetime.now() - s))

    s = datetime.datetime.now()
    o = Test.simulate3(lambda : Test.something(10), simulationRate)
    print((datetime.datetime.now() - s))

simulation()
```

Measuring the time, I get:

```
0:00:00.258000
0:00:10.348000
0:00:10.556000
```

I'm getting started with concurrency so I don't understand what is the bottleneck that prevents the threads to run faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you change your task function to this, you will see the difference:

```
def something(n):
    """ simulate doing some io based task.
    """
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return sum(1 for i in range(n))
```

On my mac pro, this gives:

```
0:00:13.774700
0:00:01.591226
0:00:01.489159
```

The concurrent.future is obvious more faster this time.

The reason is that: you are simulating a cpu based task, because of python's GIL, concurrent.future make it slower.

concurrent.future provides a high-level interface for asynchronously executing callables, you are using it for wrong scene.